# How to fill a contingency table from the marginal distributions given some optimization constraints?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming, cvxopt

I need to find the cells of a contingency table given the marginal distributions.

| 2574 | 2572 | 3393 | 3768 | 3822 | ***b*** | ***e*** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x₁₁ | x₁₂ | x₁₃ | x₁₄ | x₁₅ | **187** | 23846753.74 |
| x₂₁ | x₂₂ | x₂₃ | x₂₄ | x₂₅ | **3** | 324024.64 |
| x₃₁ | x₃₂ | x₃₃ | x₃₄ | x₃₅ | **13755** | 1489591510.50 |
| x₄₁ | x₄₂ | x₄₃ | x₄₄ | x₄₅ | **543** | 76173239.22 |
| x₅₁ | x₅₂ | x₅₃ | x₅₄ | x₅₅ | **68** | 8188751.57 |
| x₆₁ | x₆₂ | x₆₃ | x₆₄ | x₆₅ | **1332** | 172945247.86 |
| x₇₁ | x₇₂ | x₇₃ | x₇₄ | x₇₅ | **361** | 41675606.70 |

xᵢⱼ are non-negative integers I want to find. The column sums are exact. The row sums (*b*) are approximate.

There are additional constraints to guide the distribution of the xᵢⱼ:

Given constant factors *F* = (13336.41847153, 102412.73466321, 41811.01724119, 78689.83110577, 282353.66682778)<sup>T</sup> and the expected result *e* then *X·F ≈ e*

Is this a Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming problem if I want to minimize the deviations of the approximate equalities?

- *b* are the column sums
- *A* is a vector of ones, so that every column gets summed up
- *d* are the row sums
- *C* is a vector of ones, such that every row gets summed up
- *e* is a vector of expected weighted sums
- *F* is a constant vector of weights

The optimization problem can be formulated as

- min (‖ *X C – d* ‖² + ‖ *X F – e* ‖²)
- such that *A X = b*
- *x* ≥ 0
- *x* ∈ ℕ

I’ve tried to solve this using [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/):

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

F = np.array([13336.41847153, 102412.73466321, 41811.01724119, 78689.83110577, 282353.66682778])
e = [23846753.74, 324024.64, 1489591510.50, 76173239.22, 8188751.57, 172945247.86, 41675606.70]
d = [187., 3., 13755., 543., 68., 1332., 361.]
C = np.ones(len(F))
b = np.array([2574, 2572, 3393, 3768, 3822])
A = np.ones(len(d))

x = cp.Variable((len(e), len(b)), integer=True)
cost = cp.sum_squares(x @ C - d) + cp.sum_squares(x @ F - e)
objective = cp.Minimize(cost)
constraint_gt0 = x >= 0
constraint_eq = A @ x == b
    
problem = cp.Problem(objective, [constraint_gt0, constraint_eq])
solution = problem.solve()
```

But this results in the error message:

Either candidate conic solvers (['GLPK_MI', 'SCIPY']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC, NonNeg, Zero), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.

If I remove the `integer=True` constraint the method completes without error but doesn’t find a solution.

There are many of these tables to solve, which are all independent of each other. So I need a solution in code, not the set of *x* for the particular given example.

My questions:

Is this a well-formed problem and solvable?

Is it under-constrained like the error message suggests?

Why does it result in a Second-Order Cone (SOC) as mentioned in the error message? That sounds unnecessarily complicated. I thought this is a “least squares problem with some extra constraints”.

How can I solve the problem with cvxpy or some other Python package?

If an approximate, non-integer solution is more feasible, how would I achieve that?

Comment: This is called a **matrix-balancing** problem. Try using Cplex as solver (the freebie version should suffice).

Comment: The quadratic part is translated to a SOC internally for conic solvers and to a QP for QP solvers. You need a solver which supports one of that combined with mixed-integer from the table in https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints of @ErwinKalvelagen and @MichalAdamaszek: the answer is CPLEX. You need a solver that is capable of solving this class of problems. See [Choosing a solver](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver) in the cvxpy documentation.

As an alternative if you don’t want to use CPLEX, by replacing `cp.sum_squares` with `cp.norm` in the cost function and removing the `integer=True` constraint, the integrated solvers are able to find a floating point solution, too.